# React - How to assign flow type to an exported module?

Tags: reactjs, module, flowtype

I have a file like this:

```
// @flow
type Options = {
  active?: string,
  name?: string,
};

exports.myObject = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? {
  active: 'some string',
  name: 'some string',
} : {}
```

How can I assign a `type/interface` to **myObject** ? Shall I do it while importing or I have do it here in this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to define the type interface of `myObject` to be `Options`  on export for types-first. You'll want to change your file to look like this,

```
// @flow
type Options = {
  active?: string,
  name?: string,
};

exports.myObject = ((process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? {
  active: 'some string',
  name: 'some string',
} : {}): Options);
```